# How to mark a relation optional using EmbeddedId?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, embedded, hibernate-mapping, option-type

I have an entity which should join another entity. This relation is optional and uses an *EmbeddedId*.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUST_NR", referencedColumnName = "CUST_NR", insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "BILL_NR", referencedColumnName = "BILL_NR", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
@ForeignKey(name = "none")
// Field is optional, so no need for a constraint
// Need to use deprecated annotation https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8805
private Report report;
```

If I query the entity which has no related report it fails with

> javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find Report with
>   id ReportPk@62675cdb

It is working for simple IDs. What did I miss?

A working workaround would using **FetchType.LAZY**. But I want to try to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no possibility in JPA itself. If you want to use hibernate specific annotations, you can use the *[NotFound](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/NotFound.html#annotation_type_element_detail)* annotation.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUST_NR", referencedColumnName = "CUST_NR",
                insertable = false, updatable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "BILL_NR", referencedColumnName = "BILL_NR", 
                insertable = false, updatable = false)})
@ForeignKey(name = "none")
// Field is optional, so no need for a constraint
// Need to use deprecated annotation https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8805
@NotFound(NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Report report;
```

Have a look to `@NotFound(NotFoundAction.IGNORE)`.